# DocuSign REST API - EnvelopeViews createCorrect call returning USER_NOT_ENVELOPE_SENDER

Tags: docusignapi

I have a `.NET` service that uses the **DocuSign REST API** to create envelopes.  We need other DocuSign users in the same account to be able to correct documents created by the service.  The service uses the **SOBO login** (using **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header) when calling `EnvelopesApi.CreateCorrectView(account,envelopeId,options)`.

The call throws an exception with this message:

> "Error calling CreateCorrectView: { "errorCode":
>   "USER_NOT_ENVELOPE_SENDER", "message": "This user is not the sender of
>   the envelope. Only the sender of the envelope may perform the
>   requested operation."

I was able to do corrections of other users documents using the DocuSign UI without any problems.

Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You would be able to do other User documents if those Users have transferred the custody of the documents to you and you are able to see their envelopes, else it is not possible from the UI as well. If you are developing your integration with DocuSign then you should not use `X-DocuSign-Authentication` header, its not recommended now, please check [Authentication Overview](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html) instead you should use [Authorization Code Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html) or if mobile App [Implicit Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_implicit.html). You can call correctView for the user only who was the sender of the envelope, no other user can correct the other user's envelope. If envelope was created by a service/api user then you can correct envelope with the same user only.